# Poner imagen en Menú Flutter DrawerListTitle

Tags: flutter

Hola a todos tengo un proyecto realizado en flutter, pero en el área de menú el proyecto usa íconos de material... ahora quería ver si es posible cambiar por una imagen en concreto digamos en este caso particular que muestre una imagen de whatsapp, así de otra URL...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                    DrawerListTitle(
                        icon: Icons.phone_android,
                        text: I18n.current.whatsapp,
                        onTap: () async {
                          if (await canLaunch(_url)) {
                            await launch(_url, forceSafariVC: false);
                          }
                        }),
                    DrawerListTitle(
                        icon: Icons.phone_iphone,
                        text: I18n.current.telegram,
                        onTap: () async {
                          if (await canLaunch(_url)) {
                            await launch(_url2, forceSafariVC: false);
                          }
                        }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se a lo que te refieras, deberias proporcionar código para poder entender mejor tu pregunta, pero no se si te refieras a reemplazar un icono por una imagen en flutter, tienes varias opciones, te presento esta:

Una imagen desde la web:

```
ListTile(
    title: Text('Image Network'),
    leading: Container(
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      child: Image.network(
          'https://kinsta.com/es/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2017/06/c%C3%B3mo-optimizar-im%C3%A1grnrd-para-la-web-.png'),
    ));
```

Una imagen interna:

```
ListTile(
    title: Text('Asset Image'),
    leading: Container(
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      child: Image.asset(
          'assets/image.png'),
    ));
```

No se si mi respuesta haya despejado tu inquietud, pero intenta poner código para entender mejor la pregunta.

--------------------------------UPDATE---------------------

```
 ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (builder) => MiPerfil(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  tileColor: !item1 ? Colors.grey[300] : Colors.black,
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: !item1 ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Datos generales',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: !item1 ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

image[image: Quedaría algo así]:

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, he editado mi post para poner el código, veo que tu fuistes quien me ayudó en mi otra consulta, como podrás ver el flutter utiliza material de google como íconos, pero me gustaría agregar en vez de ícono vaya una imagen ya que la librería de material no tiene ícono de telegram ni whatsapp :(

Comment: Te comento, yo cuando uso menu lateral(Drawer), normalmente pongo como hijo del drawer a un ListView, dentro de este agrego hijos, los cuales son los ListTile, el listTile tiene una propiedad que se llama leading, esta propiedad me permite poner un widget, ya sea imagen, icon, etc, y en tu caso veo que necesitas una imagen, puedes reemplazar ese icono en el leading por una imagen, o mira a ver si el Widget que tu tienes, tiene la propiedad de leading, en la respuesta que te di, está un actualización con un ejemplo mas extenso y una imagen, saludos.